# In NLTK, how do I import a library of sentence structures and WordNet into CFG without hardcoding?

Tags: python, nltk, context-free-grammar, wordnet

```
S -> NP VP
**[VP -> V Det N | V Adj | V NP Det N]**
PP -> P NP
```

What I am trying to do here is to accept as many forms of sentences as possible, however currently there are only three of them hardcoded here in the bracket. Is there a library/system that allows me to accept all types of sentences/structures?
I am using this to break up sentences in books.

```
V -> "is" | "was" | "are" | "were" |
```

Also I am trying to import verbs and nouns instead of hardcoding from WordNet into CFG. The only documentation I found was about WordNet synonym functions rather than import the entire dictionary. I wonder if there is a way to import the dictionary or am I stuck hardcoding?

Comment: Write a code to output the wordnet lemmas to string that the CFG needs. BTW, it's also not very possible to use WordNet in CFG grammars because WordNet contains lemmas not surface strings, so you would get `to be` and never `is , was, are, were`; you can get `apple` from WN but not `apples`.